Are equivalent lengths different for compressible and incompressible flow?
I've been looking at estimating pressure loss using equivalent lengths of fittings. However, most of the examples and language I've seen seems to indicate this is commonly done for incompressible fluids. I don't really see any examples where this is done with compressible fluids. Is the same method and rules of thumb applicable for compressible fluids? My particular application is for exhaust piping.
Assuming speed are below sonic and there is no choked flow can you provide a good reference where such a calculation is performed?

Not necessarily. Exhaust flows can be very fast. You need to keep the flow velocity well below sonic speeds to ensure incompressible figures apply. However, there will also be huge variations in gas properties due to temperature gradients and ongoing chemical reactions in the system (like a 650 degree F change in temps), and these may have a bigger effect on backpressure unknowns. Downstream of the mufflers, you should be okay. Pressure pulse reflections caused by bends also can have a significant effect on the flow conditions and performance.

The principle for equivalent length applies in that an equivalent length exists, but because density for compressible changes with pressure making it less generic thanks to properties of the fluid being more drastically altered. Whether you put an orifice upstream or downstream of a straight can change its equivalent length in such cases since in one, you run expanding low density fluid in the straight, and in the other you run high density through the straight.
